# How to prevent redirection to another aspx page on pressing enter key on textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having one user control which contains search functionality and when i load this user control by default i am setting focus to this search `textbox`:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ToolTip="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
```

Now when i press enter key on textbox then control goes on my master page load event and that master page load event contains one method which redirects to respective url.

But this happens only on enter and control goes to master page load events and i want to stop this.

So how to prevent this??

Comment: You need to handle this in master page itself. Script won't help you in this scenario

Comment: @RahulNikate:How to handle this on master page.can you tell me in more detail?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to follow below approach. Put the textbox and button inside of a Panel and set the default button to the button you want to be activated on enter.

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
  <asp:TextBox id="txtSearch" runat="server" />
  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ToolTip="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: But enter key pressing fire load event

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Which load event you are talking here.

Comment: See my this textbox is in my user control so on enter key press load event of that user control fires

Comment: Yes that will fire. Because enter key will cause post back which will fire user control load event. If you just want to ignore enter on textbox then you can follow javascript way to do this

Comment: Is it because textbox contains runat server so page load event will fire?

Comment: no runat server is different thing. it is not the reason for postback

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the Enter-Key by using the following script:

```
$('TextBox').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: isnt this possible without any javascript or any code??

Comment: Instead OP can remove focus from textbox right than writing this script

Comment: @Learning : It is understood

Comment: @RahulNikate : removing focus is not at all a solution in this case. The problem remains there in user manualy give focus and hit enter

Comment: both the answer are correct but actually i wanted the answer for why this behaviour is happening

Answer (score 1):

Prevent enter key on textbox

```
$('[id*="txtSearch"]').keypress(function(e){
    if ( e.which == 13 ) return false;
});
```

Using C#, create KeyPress event and use this code inside it.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress=true;
}
```

You can create event using `onkeypress="__doPostBack(this.name,'OnKeyPress');"` on textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" onkeypress="__doPostBack(this.name,'OnKeyPress');"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: isnt this possible without any javascript or any code??

Comment: Instead OP can remove focus from textbox right than writing this script

Comment: @Learning no it won't.

Comment: both the answer are correct but actually i wanted the answer for why this behaviour is happening

Comment: @Learning Because by default enter key raises submit button event.

Comment: actually your solution worked no input is given to textbox and after i give any input and removes everything from textbox and press enter then again same behaviour happens and this client side event doesnt fires

Comment: i am talking about client side event

Comment: @Learning Use server side then.

Comment: can you please post your method declaration of server side events??

Comment: Use this link http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/670649/How-to-call-a-Csharp-Method-on-KeyPress-of-the-Tex